# Why the compute instance behind the NAT gateway is showing ICMP packet loss when it pings the external IP Address of the NAT Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nat

For understanding the Google Cloud Compute NAT Gateway, I have followed the [Configure a NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) documentation. As I was intended to check the connectivity inside the compute instance behind the NAT gateway, I did the following:

- Created a custom network with sub-net with range - `10.0.0.0/23`.

  ```
  $ gcloud compute networks create custom-network1 \
      --mode custom
  $ gcloud compute networks subnets create subnet-us-central-192 \
      --network custom-network1 \
      --region us-central1 \
      --range 10.0.0.0/23
  ```
- Created firewall rules to allow ssh connections `tcp:22` and `icmp` with `--source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0`.

  ```
  $ gcloud compute firewall-rules create gce-network-allow-ssh \
      --allow tcp:22 --network gce-network
  $ gcloud compute firewall-rules create gce-network-allow-internal \
      --allow tcp:1-65535,udp:1-65535,icmp --network gce-network
  ```
- Created a virtual machine to act as a NAT gateway on the new network with IP forward enabled.

  ```
  $ gcloud compute instances create nat-gateway --network gce-network \
      --can-ip-forward --zone us-central1-a \
      --image-family debian-8 --image-project debian-cloud --tags nat
  ```
- Created another virtual machine behind the NAT gateway on the same network with tag `no-ip` and no external IP attached to it.

  ```
  $ gcloud compute instances create example-instance --network gce-network \
      --no-address --zone us-central1-a \
      --image-family debian-8 --image-project debian-cloud --tags no-ip
  ```
- Created a route to send traffic through the gateway instance.

  ```
  $ gcloud compute routes create no-ip-internet-route --network gce-network \
      --destination-range 0.0.0.0/0 --next-hop-instance nat-gateway \
      --next-hop-instance-zone us-central1-a --tags no-ip --priority 800
  ```
- Inside the NAT gateway, enabled ipv4 forwarding and allowed internet access to internal instances

  ```
  $ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

After configuring the NAT gateway, i tried the following scenarios:

- Sent a `ping` request to `10.0.0.2` (NAT gateway private IP address) from internal instance, to check the connectivity between NAT gateway and internal instance. It worked fine.
- Sent a `ping` request to `google.com` from the internal instance, to check internet connectivity. It also worked fine.
- Sent a `ping` request to `104.xx.xx.xx` (NAT gateway external IP address) from internal instance, to check the connectivity between NAT gateway and internal instance. **It didn't work.**

  The dump for the packets flow is as shown:

  - The `ping` request is initiated from the internal instance to the external IP address of the NAT gateway instance.

    ```
    $ ping -c 1 104.xx.xx.xx
    PING 104.xx.xx.xx (104.xx.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.

    --- 104.xx.xx.xx ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
    ```
  - The dump of packets flow inside the NAT gateway instance as follows:

    ```
    09:07:34.062054 IP 10.0.0.3 > 104.xx.xx.xx: ICMP echo request, id 2341, seq 1, length 64
    09:07:34.062080 IP 10.0.0.2 > 104.xx.xx.xx: ICMP echo request, id 2341, seq 1, length 64
    09:07:34.062459 IP 104.xx.xx.xx > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 2341, seq 1, length 64
    09:07:34.062479 IP 10.0.0.2 > 104.xx.xx.xx: ICMP echo reply, id 2341, seq 1, length 64
    09:07:34.062574 IP 104.xx.xx.xx > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 2341, seq 1, length 64
    09:07:34.062579 IP 104.xx.xx.xx > 10.0.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 2341, seq 1, length 64
    ```
  - The dump of packets flow inside the internal instance as follows:

    ```
    09:07:34.038915 IP 10.0.0.3 > 104.xx.xx.xx: ICMP echo request, id 2341, seq 1, length 64
    ```

> Note: `10.0.0.3` and `10.0.0.2` are the private IP addresses of internal and NAT gateway instances respectively.

For my understanding, the NAT gateway is sending the `echo reply` to the internal instance. But, the internal instance is not receiving ICMP packets.

Can anyone explain the behavior of the internal instances with the external IP address of NAT gateway?

Comment: Normally you must enable "NAT loopback" in the router to achieve your goal here.

Comment: Hi @nickdnk, Is there any configuration from google cloud compute engine or networking to enable "NAT loopback"?

Comment: I don't know. Never used it. Loop back may also only be applicable in the case where a client on the internal LAN wants to connect to a service that's forwarded to a client on the same internal LAN, using the external IP. But I figured it was worth a comment.

Comment: @nickdnk, Can you give me any relative example (some blog links, etc) which addresses my problem? So that, I will work out them to replicate it with my scenario, Thanks.

Comment: I cannot. But you can google NAT loop back for an explanation. If that doesn't help you then I'm sorry, I can't either.